# How to start activity when user clicks a notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-activity

I am attempting to convert some code I found in a tutorial for my own use. Originally, the code launched the system contacts list when the user would click a notification generated by my app. I am trying to start an `Activity` of my own instead of launching the contact list, but it's not working. More specifically, nothing happens. There is no error, and my `Activity` doesn't load either. The notification window disappears after clicking, and the original `Activity` is still visible.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String deal = (String) extras.get("Deal");
        String title = "Deal found at " + (String) extras.get("LocationName");

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, title,System.currentTimeMillis());

        Class ourClass;
        try {
            ourClass = Class.forName("com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget");
            Intent startMyActivity = new Intent(context, ourClass);

            PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,startMyActivity, 0);
            notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, deal, myIntent);
            notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my entry in the `AndroidManifext.xml` file...

```
  <activity android:name=".ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

And this is my `Activity` that I want to launch...

```
public class ViewTarget extends ListActivity {
    public ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return super.getListAdapter();
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        return super.getListView();
    }

    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        super.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locations);
        Log.v("db", "Inside ViewTarget");
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. I left off the package name in the activity declaration in the Manifest file. I changed <activity android:name=".ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name" > to <activity android:name="com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name" />.  Everything works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I forgot to include the package name in the activity declaration in the Manifest file.

Wrong:

```
activity android:name=".ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Correct:

```
activity android:name="com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Answer (score 26):

Which Android version are you running on? You might wanna try using NotificationCompat instead. This class is include in the latest support package.

```java
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewTarget.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Resources res = context.getResources();
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
       .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.app_icon))
       .setTicker(payload)
       .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setContentTitle("Message")
       .setContentText(payload);
Notification n = builder.getNotification();

n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
nm.notify(0, n);
```

EDIT:
I know this is an old thread/question but this answer helped me for showing the activity when tapping the notification.
For those people that this isn't working is probably because you haven't "registered" the activity in your manifest. For example:

```xml
<activity
   android:name="com.package.name.NameOfActivityToLaunch"
   android:label="Title of Activity" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.package.name.NAMEOFACTIVITYTOLAUNCH" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And, hopefully, this should work.
Hope it helped...

Comment: I tested mine on 2.1+ so this should work. The existing Notification is being deprecated(probably not very soon).

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I pasted the code in and Eclipse can't resolve NotificationCompat, nor does it offer an import suggestion. What namespace is this from?  Thanks

Comment: I added the code.  But it does not load the activity.  The notification fires and nothing happens when clicking it. Notification goes away and default screen is still visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, I'd suggest you do one of the following: 1) Remove Intent filter and make sure your ViewTarget class is the same class as specified. 2) Add a new Activity to check if it launch (perhaps hello world). I started to think that something in the ViewTarget activity killed it before it has any chance to react. Just a guess but worth trying nonetheless.

Comment: OK I'll add a new activity.  Can it just be an empty activity that extends ACTIVITY?  Or should I add UI elements?

Comment: I removed the intent filter and created a simple new activity. Same result.  Doesn't appear to load.  I have a Log.v in the new activity and it is never logged. So it doesn't appear to be created.

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT made, hopefully it works and helps others. For those people that this isn't working is probably because you haven't "registered" the activity in your manifest. For example: `<activity
   android:name="com.package.name.NameOfActivityToLaunch"
   android:label="Title of Activity" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.package.name.NAMEOFACTIVITYTOLAUNCH" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Comment: For me, the key was the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

you should set action and category for Intent.

```
Intent startMyActivity = new Intent(context, ourClass);
startMyActivity .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMyActivity .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing the Intent filter, so it looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Also, not sure if this code will work:

`ourClass = Class.forName("com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget");
Intent startMyActivity = new Intent(context, ourClass);`

Can you try it like this instead:

`Intent startMyActivity = new Intent(context, ViewTarget.class);`

Comment: Removed the intent filter, and swapped out my Intent initialization code for yours.  Still nothing :(  Just sits at the default/main activity after clicking the notification.

Comment: Is the ViewTarget Activity already running (is that your default/main activity?)

Comment: No it is not running. There is a separate activity which is the MAIN activity.

Comment: I have similar code in one of my apps... the only real difference now is the ID that you set on the call to `notify`. Can you try `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID` ?

Comment: It's also possible that the call to notify doesn't work if the ID is 0. (Would be 0, since you never initialize SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID)

Comment: Changed it to (int) System.currentTimeMillis(). Still nothing :(  Clicking the notification simply closes the notification slider window showing my default form.  I wish I could be more helpful with debugging but I am still learning java and the android system.  Is there anything I can add to help test and find the culprit?  Null checks?

Comment: Can you try watching the logcat output when you click? This tutorial gives a good overview of debugging with the logcat tool: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Comment: Here's 2 lines of relevant output:

1) 04-17 23:47:11.047: I/ActivityManager(82): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=kjdv.gpsVegas/com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget bnds=[0,387][480,483] }

2) 04-17 23:47:11.417: W/InputManagerService(82): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44b57030

Comment: OK I figured out the problem.  I forgot the package name in the Android Manifest file activity declaration.  I changed it to: <activity android:name="com.kjdv.gpsVegas.ViewTarget" android:label="@string/app_name" /> and it worked.  Thank you so much for looking into this and helping me debug. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, glad you were able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

check this code

```
            public class TestActivity extends Activity {
private static final int UNIQUE_ID = 882;

public static NotificationManager nm;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent navigationIntent = new Intent();


    navigationIntent.setClass(classname.this, MainActivity.class);


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent,
            0);

    String body = "New notificattion added!!!";
    String title = "Notification";


    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

            //this is for giving number on the notification icon

    n.number = Integer.parseInt(responseText);

    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    nm.notify(UNIQUE_ID, n);
```

Comment: Hmmm...this isn't working.  I changed nm.notify to n.notify (assumed it was a typo).  Then Eclipse removed my params from the Notify() method call to match the API.  Is there a version of Notification.Nofity that has parameters?

Comment: sorry for late reply....i am edited my code.nm is the instance of notification manager

Answer (score 1):

In order to launch an `Activity` from an `Intent`, you need to add a flag:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This is true even if you declare the class in the `Intent`'s constructor.

Comment: I added this. Unfortunately it made no difference.  The activity doesn't load.  Just sits at the default/main activity screen