# Start a new activity on notification icon click

Tags: android

I can already show an icon in the notification bar, as shown in the code below. I want to start a new activity (`myclass`) when the user clicks this icon, but I don't know how to do this. Where should I place the intent?

```
public class NotificationActivity extends Activity {
    AlarmManager am;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        setRepeatingAlarm();
    }

    public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            (20 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        System.out.println("Calling Alaram...");
    }
}



public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    NotificationManager nm;

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("in broad....");

        nm = (NotificationManager) context  .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = "Lokesh";
        CharSequence message = "Notification Test...";
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(), 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.cherry_icon,
            "Notification Test...", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        nm.notify(1, notif);

        if ((intent.getAction() != null) &&  
                (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
        {
            System.out.println("in broadcast receiver.....");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            context.startActivity(i);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you declared your new activity in the manifest? @NiceGuy

Comment: yes is declair but where i place intent in this code to start new activity when click on icon on notification bar???

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184351/how-to-start-activity-when-user-clicks-a-notification

Answer (score 1):

The pending intent that you give to the Notification builder should contain a intent that will launch an activity when the notification is clicked by the user. You need to create an intent to launch one of your activities:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
```

Then you make a pendingIntent using this intent:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

and then you create a notification using it. When a user clicks your notification, `ResultActivity` will be launched.

The whole code snippet:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);

// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Go through the detailed article in the developer docs for a great explanation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: nice solution, but this only works if you have more than one activity, if you have only one and this one it is singleInstance, Notification to bring Activity into foreground only if it is in background the screen stay blank.