# When I start a Activity from a Notification the MainActivity is also started

Tags: android, notifications

In my app I have a `Activity` that is started when the user clicks in a app Notification.

Sometimes, when the user clicks the Notification, the `Activity` is displayed correctly, but sometimes the `MainActivity` for the app is also started back the correct `Activity`, and displayed when user clicks back in the correct `Activity`.

I have tried adding `"android:launchMode=singleTask"` to the 
`AlertActionReceiverActivity`, that is the `Activit`y that is launched from the Notification and also no adding it, but the result is the same.

Any luck to solve this issue?

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>  

<activity android:name=".AlertActionReceiverActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent" />
```

Comment: Refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184351/how-to-start-activity-when-user-clicks-a-notification) and see if it can help you

Comment: Share your notification code here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because on Android, by default, when you go back, it is the parent activity which is displayed, and not the previous one.

The solution is explained on Android doc: it is to use a pendingIntent with special flags: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse

(just be careful with API compatibility!!)

I hope this helped

Comment: Seems to working fine after add taskAffinity="" modifier to the NotificationActivity and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to the Notification flags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  

    <activity
        android:name=".AlertActionReceiverActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ABCActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:theme="@style/AppThemeTransparent">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ABCActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Also create proper TaskStack:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    Intent notifyIntent =
        new Intent(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class));
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent notifyPIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        notifyPIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    builder.setContentIntent(notifyPIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I'm not sure if I'm capable to follow it... You are using the same variable name for a Intent and also for a PendingIntent and not sure if I understand why you define the TaskStackBuilder if after define it you aren't assigning to the Notification at all. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @TheMatrix Well you didn't provide any code , so i just took variable as per my own. But if this is helpful in anyway you can upvote.